# Is it against rules to add a closing statement to an answer or question?

Tags: support, etiquette, policy

Whenever I answer a question I would always conclude it with what I feel to be a proper closing such as "I hope this helped you. You have a wonderful day!". However on certain sites people of a much higher reputation with remove them from the end of my answers, but not all sites. I have not seen such a rule barring one from doing this, so I am confused why it was removed.

- is it seen as off topic?
- is it seen as detracting from the answer?
- Is there actually a rule that prohibits this?

Comment: Every Tour says "no chit chat". I think signatures, greetings, thanks, sign-offs and anything not focused on the actual Q&A is chit chat and should be omitted/removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the sense that... it's noise.

We don't like noise. Your question isn't just helping you, it's helping others, and 5-10 or even 15 years down the road, your politeness will be irrelevant. The person seeking it will get answers.

It's enough of an issue that we have a standard moderation message for this (as well as signatures), and part of it explains both the confusion you have, and why we do things the way we do...

> Coming from your traditional discussion forums, I understand that it is often customary to be a bit more cordial and chatty in your posts, but at Stack Exchange, one of our goals is to build a library of high-quality questions and answers where it's as easy as possible to find the best answer. I know this can come across as a bit persnickety — this crazy Q&A site that hates conversation — but it's that "just the answers" ethos that results in over 90% of the questions getting great answers, often stunningly quickly.

If you want to make someone's day, upvote the post, pick the best answer and close the loop. Be responsive and edit in additional information as needed (which is the *best thing*!). If you end up self resolving, post an answer. In a sense, "focus on the content not the people" is one of the hardest things to get about using SE effectively.

It's okay to keep it technical, and to the point, simply because that's how we do things.

Comment: Courtesy and politeness is never irrelevant otherwise  SE would not have created the CoC.

Comment: Could you post the link to the quotation, please? I'm curious to see when it was written or last updated.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's from a moderator template message, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320804/1288408

Comment: Thank you @ModusTollens but I fear the statistic `that results in over 90% of the questions getting great answers,` and `often stunningly quickly.` is no longer true (certainly not true on EL&U!)  and I was wondering how old that message/template was.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Are many questions closed on EL&U? It would make sense to not include them when calculating the percentage of answered questions.

Comment: @ModusTollens around 50% of questions on EL&U are closed for being off-topic but that's changing because the review queue is lagging,  and quite a few questions end up unanswered. When they are answered, it's often by a low rep user. But I was wondering if the 90% figure was true for Stack Overflow, I could check...

Comment: @ModusTollens Took me some time but I found the stats, "only" **71%** of questions on Stack Overflow are answered https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questions, so the message is definitely untrue.

Comment: There in comes an interesting problem for me - I have a new user who dosen't know "our" ways. I can advice him based on what he'd expect to see if he did it, and try to get him on the right path - noise free posts, or bog him down in details. The most polite thing to do on SE is to write a good, clear, answerable question with a minimum of fluff. If we don't look at just the stats, I feel the rest of it was relevant to the *real* question OP was asking - whether pleasantries and salutations have a place on SE. Which... they have never.